# FOSElastica don't recognize my ElasticSearch username and password

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I've setup users and roles on my ElasticSearch and while it works like a charm with curl it doesn't seem to work through FOSElastica. I'm using it to populate my ElasticSearch indices.

I've tried to setup username and password through fos_elastica config file (like shown [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/cookbook/http-auth-for-elastica.md)) with no success :

```
fos_elastica:
    serializer: 
        serializer: jms_serializer
    clients:
        default: 
            host: localhost 
            port: 9200
            username: 'elastic'
            paswword: 'password'
```

I've even tried to hard setup username and password in Http.php in Elastica files, same no success and no changes in the error message, it keeps telling me :

```
In Http.php line 182:

  action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [anonymous_user]
```

Like there's no username/password at all.
Anyone encountered that problem ?

EDIT : 
I found something interesting : line 107 of Http.php in Elastica files is

`curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);`

And it doesn't work for ElasticSearch Xpack authentication.

But, if you change CURLATUH_ANY to CURLAUTH_BASIC, it actually works.

I'll open an issue on github.

EDIT : issue opened [here](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/issues/1638)